# jCarousel text wrap issue on Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, css, jcarousel

I am using jCarousel. The problem is only in Chrome and Safari; the text gets wrapped/mangled.

I've done a lot of debugging and couldn't find cause of this issue.

Can any one please help me with this issue

[See it at this URL.](http://www.allposters.com/gallery.asp?startat=/getthumb.asp&txtSearch=flower&CID=27D3FFF2C92A48699EAC56D838836932)

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has some problem with the width ,

!important is taking precedence over in-line css for chrome and safari.

I removed !important from css and it started working fine.